# is it possible to create Spark data frame on unstructured data file which does not have any delimiter

Tags: apache-spark-sql

is it possible to create Spark data frame  on unstructured data file which does not have any delimiter?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.